# YARN add new queue or clear default queue

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I'm running YARN on an EMR cluster.

`mapred queue -list` returns:

```
Queue Name : default
Queue State : running
Scheduling Info : Capacity: 100.0, MaximumCapacity: 100.0, CurrentCapacity: 0.0
```

How do I clear this queue or add a new one? I've been looking for a while now and can't find CLI commands to do so. I only have access to CLI. Any Spark applications I submit hang in the ACCEPTED state, and I've killed all submitted applications via `yarn app --kill [app_id]`

Answer (score 0):

`CurrentCapacity: 0.0` means that the queue is fully unused.

Your jobs, if thats your concern, are NOT hung due to unavailability of resources.

Not sure whether EMR allows yarn cli commands such as schedulerconf

[https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#queue:~:text=ResourceManager%20admin%20client-,schedulerconf,-Usage%3A%20yarn](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnCommands.html#queue:%7E:text=ResourceManager%20admin%20client-,schedulerconf,-Usage%3A%20yarn)